# Stating a Distribution

Tags: distributions, random-variable

Suppose,

− X has a t-distribution with 17 degrees of freedom

− Y has a $χ_8^2$ distribution

− Z has a standard normal distribution

− Y, and Z are independent.

State the distribution of the following random variable.  Include the name of the family of distributions as well as the value(s) of any parameter(s).

$W_2 = Y + Z^2$

I believe this is a chi squared plus a chi squared. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the relevance of $X$ in your question but the sum of two independent $\chi^2$ random variables (as $Y$ and $Z^2$ are stated to be in your question) is a $\chi^2$ random variable whose number of degrees of freedom is the sum of the numbers of degrees of the two $\chi^2$ random variables.  In short, the answer to the question asked in your last paragraph is Yes.

Comment: As the answer says it is a chi square.  The degrees of freedom is 9 since Z$^2$  is chi square with 1 degree of freedom.  Also I agree that X doesn't seem to enter into the question